# designing data layer for a .net app

Tags: .net, entity-framework, database-design, ado.net, data-access-layer

I am developing a small app in .net. This app basically calls 6 to7 stored proc and 3 tables and then updates data to another table. I thought using entity framework with repository pattern was an overkill for this. A data layer class with static methods looks too simple.

Any thoughts on how to design data layer ?

Comment: Just a thought.. designing a data access layer with best practices using entity framework based on model first or data base first would not be that complex with latest VS 2012/ 2012 tooling. There are other solutions such as nhibernate llblgen (free and commercial) that would help you to do the same. Alternately you could create a couple of methods in a dll that would expose CRUD functions using pure sql.

Comment: Think **CQS**: Command Query Segregation. A bit of more code, but a lots of simplicity at the end. The more I develop, the less I believe in the CRUD style. Why? Because user's don't think CRUD, but think with tasks and commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Entity Framework works well with or without Repositories!

One of the Repository Pattern's goal is to add an abstraction layer between Doamin and Data layers.

If you're creating a simple application, where you're the only developper involved, keep in mind [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it) principles!

Just create a Presentation layer, that will call Services in a Business layer, that will be responsible to call EF like this:

```
public void InsertThings(Entity1 entity1)
{
  using (var context = new MyContext())
  {
    var entity1 = new Entity1 { Name = "My first Entity" };
    context.Entity1.Add(entity1);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}

public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
  var customers = db.customers

  return customers.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks...I am writing a repository class(not the actuall patern) which just has methods to access data using EF and return it to BL. sounds ok ?

Comment: Sounds ok. By the way there's not only one way to implement the repository pattern. Have a look at this [SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224015/entity-framework-4-1-generic-repository-set-up/17232382#17232382) where @zhx was wondering if he needed whether to use generic repository or not...